# forbidden chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

We wish to show below chromatic polynomial are not exist; It means that we couldn't find any graph that has one of these chromatic polynomial

1-  $\ k^5 - 4k^4 + 8k^3 - 4k^2 +k$

2- $\ k^4 - 3k^3 + k^2$

3- $\ k^7 - k^6 + 1$

The chromatic polynomial is a polynomial:

$\pi_{k}(G)$ := the number of graph colorings with k color

It counts the number of graph colorings as a function of the number of colors

here k is the number of colors

For example:

$\pi_{k}(k_{n})$ = k(k-1)...(k-(n-1))

note that $\chi(k_{n})$ = n

in below link you could see more examples of chromatic polynomial

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticPolynomial.html

and we can find a chromatic polynomial of a graph recursively

If G is simple, then

$\pi(G) = \pi(G - e) - \pi(G. e)$ for any edge of G.

for simple graphs we can go more in detail... the coefficient of the largest element is 1 and the other elements have none positive and none negative coefficient. and the constant element is -m.

while;

m = |E(G)|

Answer (score 2):

First, I should correct one of your statements. It is not the constant term that equals $-m$, but the coefficient of the highest-degree-but-one term. That is, if the graph has $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, then the chromatic polynomial (which has degree $n$) has the term $-mk^{n-1}$.

If a graph has at least one edge, then it has no $1$-colorings. Thus, the chromatic polynomial evaluated at $1$ must be $0$. Equivalently, the sum of all the coefficients must be $0$.

Now, looking at the polynomials, the numbers of edges for a corresponding graph are $4$, $3$, and $1$ respectively. Thus, the sum of the coefficients must be $0$ in each case. But the polynomials have coefficient sums $2$, $-1$, and $1$ respectively, so we would have a contradiction if any of them were the chromatic polynomial of a graph.

Other arguments can be made. For instance, the constant term of a chromatic polynomial is always $0$, which excludes the third polynomial you listed.